# Using Google Pay in a Expo react native web

Tags: javascript, expo, google-play

So I have created an expo app and its a website, anbd now I am want to use Google Pay for internal purchases, so I visited their site and made my searches.

Now what I wonder is can I use the package:
npm install @google-pay/button-react

So this package is meant to be used with React web, can I use it with Expo?

I used this source:
https://github.com/google-pay/google-pay-button/tree/main/src/button-react#readme

and they have given details for react web, now I am wondering will it produce any future problems.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.